# Geforce driver is crashing continuously on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, nvidia-geforce

I have a laptop with an NVIDIA Geforce GT 740M inside, the newest driver is installed.

I am using windows 10 since the first insider preview, and I cant start any program what requires directx. When I try to, I face the following problems:

- Usually the video has black squares all around the screen like [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BFCxUo6RjWE)
- I get GPU driver related errors like this:

  > application.exe has been blocked from accessing graphics hardware.

  Or this one:

  > **Display driver stopped responding and has recovered**
  >
  > Display driver NVIDIA Windows Kernel Mode Driver, Version 361.43 stopped responding and sucessfully recovered.

Anybody has any solution for it? In the beginning there were discussions about this performance issues but not nowadays, so maybe it was fixed for the others but not for me. What could I do to solve this issue?

Comment: I've made a habit of *never* updating gfx drivers, especially NVIDIA

Comment: Are you still using the preview version?

Answer (score 1):

Mostly, this error is caused by GPU heat, Windows shuts down (block) the GPU to prevent it from heat damages. So, cooling the GPU and lowering some NVIDIA settings could fix this issue.

For the settings matter, you can follow the following instructions :

**Setting up your Nvidia settings:**

- Open **Nvidia Control Panel** and go to **Manage 3D Settings**
- Click on **Global Settings**
- Under the **Preferred graphics processor** drop-list, choose **High-performance NVIDIA processor**.
- Under the **Settings**, **Set CUDA - GPUs** to **NVIDIA GPU**.
- Under the **Settings**, TURN OFF **vSync** (Vertical sync).
- Click **Apply**
- Now go to **Configure Surround, PhysX**, and TURN ON **PhysX** (just choose your GPU under PhysX settings.)
- Click **Apply**, and CLOSE Nvidia Control Panel.

**Setting up your Power Settings**

- Go to Windows 10 Settings
- Click on **System**, and then go to **Power & sleep**.
- Click on **Additional power settings**.
- Change the power settings to **High Performance**.
- **Close**.

Another fix could solve this issue, is to turn off NVIDIA SHIELD (if you don't use it), since there are people who experienced the same issue from NVIDIA Shield streaming services.

**Turn off NVIDIA SHIELD**

- Go to Windows **Control Panel** > **Services**
- Stop & Disable **NVIDIA Streamer Network Service**
- Stop & Disable **NVIDIA Streamer Service**
- **Restart your computer**.

Comment: @Raystafarian Sorry, I just type it in a quicky way, I hope now my answer is informative enough ;).

Comment: I think you are probably right, especially with the black squares etc. However, the error message is caused by the windows "TDR" function. The problem is that something hangs the driver (probably heat in this case), and the driver is "recovered," but this happens several times in rapid succession. I believe that after a default 5 times, Windows will block the application so as to prevent further re-re-recovery ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff568187%28v=vs.85%29.aspx )

Answer (score 0):

Try rolling back to a previous version after removing the current driver in safe mode with [Display Driver Uninstaller](http://www.guru3d.com/files-details/display-driver-uninstaller-download.html), and wait for a new driver.

Comment: The previous driver has the same issues, this issue exists since the start of the insider images.